# Putting floating point ranges into bins

Tags: python, range, floating, binning

Given 5 ranges

```
[(0., 0.), (0., 0.3), (0.3, 0.5), (0.5, 0.8), (0.8, 1.0)]
```

that corresponds to:

- [0.0, 0.0]
- (0.0, 0.3]
- (0.3, 0.5]
- (0.5, 0.8]
- (0.8, 1.0]

And a list of input floats:

```
[0.5293113408538,
 0.3105914215541,
 0.7748290363338001,
 0.7745464933980998,
 0.17276995816109997,
 0.83335888200110002,
 0.0]
```

The goal is to bin the floats into the ranges above and output:

```
[3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 0]
```

I have tried this:

```
score_ranges =  [(0., 0.), (0., 0.3), (0.3, 0.5), (0.5, 0.8), (0.8, 1.0)]

x = [0.5293113408538,
 0.3105914215541,
 0.7748290363338001,
 0.7745464933980998,
 0.17276995816109997,
 0.83335888200110002,
 0.0]

binning = []

for i in x:
    for j, (start, end) in enumerate(score_ranges):
        if i == 0:
            binning.append(0)
            break
        elif start < i <= end:
            binning.append(j)
            break
```

**But is there a less verbose way to get the desired bining outputs?**

**Additionally, the zero range is sort of hard coded there because its lower bound is inclusive unlike the other classes, is there a better way to handle that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bisect module, but you'll have to change your code a little. Shrink you list of tuples to the list of floats.

```
import bisect

score_ranges =  [0., 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0]
binning = []

x = [
    0.5293113408538,
    0.3105914215541,
    0.7748290363338001,
    0.7745464933980998,
    0.17276995816109997,
    0.83335888200110002,
    0.0]

for a in x:
    binning.append(bisect.bisect_left(score_ranges, a))
```